# Move cursor left/right while entering isearch

Tags: motion, isearch

How can I move my cursor left and right while entering my `isearch` text?

1. `isearch-forward`
2. Enter some text
3. Press cursor left to edit the search text

Argh! Emacs returns the cursor to the main buffer.

I tried `(setq isearch-allow-scroll t)`, but this doesn't seem to do anything. I even tried `(setq search-exit-option nil)`, which gives an error, even with `emacs -q`.

```
Error in pre-command-hook (isearch-pre-command-hook): (wrong-type-argument characterp left)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run the command `isearch-edit-string` pressing `M-e`. See the documentation for details.

Comment: Thankyouthankyouthankyou. This has driven me nuts forever. I looked everywhere for this!

Answer (score 4):

@matteol answered your question.  Here is some further info about this.

During Isearch, keys you press that are defined in `isearch-mode-map` act according to their bindings there.  Keys that are not defined in that keymap act as they would outside Isearch.

By default, `C-b` is not bound in `isearch-mode-map`, and its `global-map` binding of `backward-char` is invoked when you use it during Isearch.  That exits Isearch. Likewise for `<left>` (bound to `left-char` globally) and other cursor-movement keys.

If you use [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) then you can customize user option **`isearchp-initiate-edit-commands`** to specify that various commands (typically cursor movement commands) should *not* exit Isearch but should instead initiate Isearch edit.

This is a convenience feature, so you can just hit `<left>` or `C-b` to both: (1) initiate editing of the Isearch pattern and (2) move the cursor within that pattern.  This is so convenient that by default the option value does include both `<left>` and `C-b` (as well as `M-<left>`, `M-b`, `C-M-<left>`, and `C-M-b`, which back the cursor up by a word and a sexp, respectively).

`C-h v isearchp-initiate-edit-commands` says:

> **`isearchp-initiate-edit-commands`** is a variable defined in [`isearch+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el).
>
> Its value is  `(backward-char left-char backward-sexp backward-word left-word)`
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Commands whose key bindings initiate Isearch edit.
>
> When invoked by a key sequence, Isearch edits the search string,
>   applying the command to it immediately.
>
> Commands you might want to include here are typically commands that
>   move point to the left, possibly deleting text along the way.
>
> Set this to `nil` if you always want all such commands to exit Isearch
>   and act on the buffer text.
>
> You can customize this variable.